# How to implement a high performance asynchronous socket server application in PHP?

Tags: php, sockets, asynchronous

With nodejs, it's very easy to create a non-blocking TCP server. Example from nodejs.org:

```
var net = require('net');
var server = net.createServer(function (socket) {
  socket.write("Echo server\r\n");
  socket.pipe(socket);
});
server.listen(1337, "127.0.0.1")
```

nodejs handles the select()-/poll()-/epoll() stuff for you, the socket routines and the main loop are implemented in C, so it's very fast and efficient.

nodejs is great, but I'd like to implement a high performance TCP socket server in PHP,  because I'm a PHP guy :)

So, one thing I already tried is to implement the socket routines in PHP, with `socket_create_listen`, `socket_accept`, `socket_select` etc. and the main loop in PHP. This works very well, but I don't think it's very efficient, because I have to use `socket_select` which calls the C-function `select` internally, but `epoll` would be better I think (I'm using Linux), but `epoll` is not available as PHP function.
([phpsocketdaemon](http://code.google.com/p/phpsocketdaemon/) and [phpmio](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmio/) are 2 projects I found that implement the socket-routines for you).

Would it be possible to do it the nodejs way? I'm thinking about a PHP module that implements the loop and socket routines in C, and calls PHP callback functions for events (`onread`, `onerror`..). Or is it not worth the effort?

Comment: /high performance TCP socket server in PHP/ looks like an oxymoron if I ever saw one.

Comment: As much of a PHP fan as I am, it really wasn't designed for this kind of usage.  You might be able to implement a server in it, but I'd say doing it in an efficient manner would be a real feat. Unless PHP undergoes some major architectural changes to allow this kind of use I'd recommend using something better suited to the task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a typical case of "If all you have is a hammer, everything looks like a nail."

As you yourself already figured out, php is not the right tool for the job. You can probably find a way to do it anyway, but it'll most likely be messy.

So use the right tool for the job. You would not use a hammer to drive a screw into the wall, would you?

Comment: More like you wouldn't rodeo with a Humvee instead of a horse.

Comment: I agree that PHP is not the best tool for this. But developers are often faced with situations where they have no control over the server that the code runs on so installing nodejs or another alternative may not be a possibility. I experience this a lot in my day to day job working for a agency where we write code and ship it out to clients who deploy it on their own environments and all we know is that our code has to run on a standard PHP stack. And sometimes we don't even have access to phpinfo(). I think it's important to stay objective and find a solution to the problem in front of you.